# Favorite Question notification

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, notifications

It would be helpful if a question could be marked so that you get a notification when there is new activity. Just something like the red notification you get when a comment gets a response.

Comment: I don't use them very often, but I thought there was a notification on your profile page under the "Favorites" section when new activity on any of your favorited questions occurs.

Comment: As this change would have to be implemented across the entire Stack Exchange family, it might be better to ask on [meta.se]. (And try [a quick search of that site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=favorite+is%3Aquestion) to see if something similar has been asked before, so you can ask from a position of knowledge.)

Comment: It would be, wouldn't it.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/83343/239016 on meta.SE.

Comment: We now have the follow feature which pushes an inbox notification through on activity on a followed post.

Answer (score 6):

It's not perfect; the system could be made to bring more attention via inbox notifications, but it does alert you to activity on your Favorites.

Clicking through to your profile, you'll see badge notifications on each area of activity. In this case, there has been two actions on a favorited question of mine.

[image: favorites]

Comment: Wow, so **that's** what the number in front of "favorites" means! I'd been wondering about that.

Answer (score 4):

What you're asking for is pretty much implemented by the new SE-wide feature of being able to "follow" posts as well as bookmark them:

[The Follow Questions and Answers feature is now live across the Network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661/278659)

If you've clicked "follow" on a post, then you will get a little red inbox notification for every new interaction (comment, edit, etc.) on the post.